# Custom utc now date function returns same result

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Code:

```
def setup_function(function):
    db.query('''
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION now_utc() RETURNS timestamp as $$
      select now() at time zone 'utc';
    $$ language sql;
    ''')

def teardown_function(function):
    db.query('DROP FUNCTION now_utc();')

def test_one ():
    print datetime.datetime.utcnow(), db.query('select now_utc();')[0]
    time.sleep(5)
    print datetime.datetime.utcnow(), db.query('select now_utc();')[0]

def test_two ():
    print datetime.datetime.utcnow(), db.query('select now_utc();')[0]
    time.sleep(5)
    print datetime.datetime.utcnow(), db.query('select now_utc();')[0]
```

Results:

```
test_one:
2017-02-28 15:51:19.962640 <Record {"now_utc": "2017-02-28T15:51:19.962945" }>
2017-02-28 15:51:24.974434 <Record {"now_utc": "2017-02-28T15:51:19.962945" }>

test_two:
2017-02-28 15:51:24.999673 <Record {"now_utc": "2017-02-28T15:51:25.000101" }>
2017-02-28 15:51:30.007059 <Record {"now_utc": "2017-02-28T15:51:25.000101" }>
```

Problem:

I am using [Records](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records) which is a thin layer on top of alchemy. The problem I am having is that now_utc returns the same datetime within each test.

Comment: use `clock_timestamp()` instead of `now()` - now() is a time of transaction start, not statement

Comment: Does the test framework you are using put tests in a transaction to roll back after the tests? If so, Postgres freezes the time during transactions to give a consistent image of "now"

Comment: @JimDeville it seems to be the case as Vao Tsun comment solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `clock_timestamp()` instead of `now()` - `now()` is a time of transaction start, not statement. [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

> now() Current date and time (start of current transaction)
>
> clock_timestamp() timestamp with time zone    Current date and time
>   (changes during statement execution);